# How to make an array of elements which not in range of another array

Tags: php

There is an array of numbers from 0 to 10000

```
$a = array();
$a = range(0,10000);
```

I have some values which are dynamic coming from database are in array like

```
$b = array("100-200","400-500","700-900");
```

so basically i want an array that will look like

```
array("0-100","200-400","500-700","900-10000");
```

for example-> if i started a value from 0 so it will break on 100.so i will get 0-100 as first element of an array,then nothing will happen until 200.Again 200 the value will start and go to 400 and will stop then i get 200-400.After that nothing will happen until 500.it will again start with 500 and will stop on 700.so i will get third element as 500-700 and so on...

Anybody can help?

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are facing?

Comment: Your `$a` will contain `1,2,3,4,5,6....10000` as values whereas `$b` has a range as values. How exactly should the filter be applied?

Comment: array_merge will not do what the OP wants @IdanMagled

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? I couldn't understand in the question. Do you want an array of ranges that go from 0 to 10000 and are not in $b ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want your ranges to be as string element of array, try this:

```
<?php
    $b = array("400-500","700-900","100-200");
    asort($b);//new line to sort the ranges
    $MIN = 0;
    foreach($b as $rang){
      $limits = explode('-', $rang);
      $result[] =  $MIN." - ".$limits[0];
      $MIN =  $limits[1];
    }
    $result[] =  $MIN." - 10000";
    print_r($result);
?>
```

Comment: @RyanVincent You just need to add a quick if for that case, but the OP should specify what should happen in some specific cases ... anyway ... it's a starting point to developing what's needed (in my answer I did check for the possibility, but other than that the answers are the same)

Comment: @Mohammad Alabed can you tell me the solution $b = array("400-500","700-900","100-200"); if we modify the array like this it giving me wrong values. Can you please help me out with this?

Comment: @AnuragJain, I have modified the code, try it pls ...

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
<?php

$b = array( "100-200","400-500","700-900" );
$c = array();

$starting = 0;
$ending = 100000;
$last = $starting;

$a = array(); // not being used
$a = range( $starting, $ending ); // not being used

foreach( $b as $k => $v )
{
    $values = explode(  '-' , $v);
    if ( $values[0] > $starting && $values[0] < $ending )
    {
        $c[] = $last.'-'.$values[0];
        $last = $values[1];
        if ( $last <= $ending && $k == count( $b ) -1 )
        {
            $c[] = $last.'-'.$ending;
        }
    }
}

print_r( $c );

?>
```

Please bear in mind that I did not use the original `$a` array for anything. I don't understand it's purpose, unless it's not actually generated from a range, and if so this could should be changed as well

Comment: Yes, I did test my code. It outputs `Array ( [0] => 0-100 [1] => 200-400 [2] => 500-700 [3] => 900-100000 )`, exactly what the OP showed in the example. ( The op never said it grows by 200 )